# Move text and put image jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I want to replace some headers by images, so I would have nice font.For example

```
<div class="latest_news">
  Latest News
</div>
```

For SEO there would be text, but for user - nice image. Also jquery script could recodnise links, so if i want to replace email address, it still would be clickable. For example:

```
<div class="email_me">
  <a href="mailto:info@mydomain.com">info@mydomain.com</a>
</div>
```

script should replace/move text to be invisible and put

```
<div class="email_me">
  <a href="mailto:info@mydomain.com"><img src="images/email.png" style="...;border:0;" alt="info@mydomain.com" /></a>
</div>
```

How can i do that in jquery/css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web fonts would be the optimal solution. But here is a jQuery one:

`$('.email_me a').html('<img src="..." style="..." alt="..." />');`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/6b874/

Answer (score 2):

Probably better off using webfonts (http://www.google.com/webfonts/ or something similar). These don't cause any the problems that happen when using images and most browser are supported.

Answer (score 1):

try this style:

```
#email_me { 
   width : ...
   height: ...
}

#email_me a {
   display     : block;
   width       : 100%;
   height      : 100%;
   overflow    : hidden;
   text-indent : 100%;
   font        : 0/0 a;
   background  : url(images/email.png) top left no-repeat;
}
```

I didn' tried but the whole area should remain clickable.